# symfony server:ca:install fails (Symfony 5 LTS)

Tags: symfony

When I run that command and try to install the certificates, I always get

```
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
```

But I haven't setup a password. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This command creates and install certificates in user home directory (~) under .symfony5/certs folder. Sample of path in Windows : `C:\Users\John Doe\.symfony5\certs`.

You can delete the contents of the certs directory and reload `symfony server:ca:install` to reinstall the certificate from scratch.

Comment: I did it like you've described it. I'm working on ubuntu 20.04 lts, so I've deleted the .symfony/certs directory completely. When running again I get:

symfony server:ca:install
You might have to enter your root password to install the local Certificate Authority certificate
Sudo password:
The local CA is now installed in the system trust store!
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
....

So it reinstalls, but failed again :(

Comment: Cheat, did you try @Stefan to reinstall the Symfony binary after my procedure before the `symfony server:ca:install` command ?

Comment: I've changed my symfony client from an old one (downloaded from symfony.com) to a new one, which is now installed by ubuntu repository "deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.symfony.com/apt/ /"

Comment: Okay, but it still doesn't work, right? @Stefan

Comment: By any chance, don't you use other ways to manage certificates on this server such as mkcert or certbot?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. I'll don't use other tools. It's an ubuntu desktop computer and it worked with the outdated symfony-cli client from the symfony website. But now using the updated symfony-cli from repository (Symfony CLI version 5.4.11), it doesn't work any more.